# unlock-bde application not found error prevalent in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bitlocker

I have encrypted a drive with BitLocker in Windows 8 Pro, but the drive will not auto-unlock.    I can manually unlock the drive from BitLocker in the Control Panel.  However from Windows Explorer, I keep seeing the "unlock-bde" command that reports the error "application not found."  Anyone know how to permanently fix this issue so it will auto-unlock the encrypted drive upon login to Windows 8 and it does not reoccur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the drive in, unlock it, in an elevated command prompt enter
`manage-bde -autounlock -enable X:` where `X:` is the drive letter.

Comment: Tried it: Works better than Microsoft's own FixIT solution. thx :-)